# function to move character/camera when button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I'm new here and also new with web coding. So i am trying to make a function to move my game character when a button is pressed. When button is pressed down a boolean value changes to "true" and the character moves. I was trying to do it somehow like this. Can someone light me up what is the best way to make this work? I need also to do this for all the rest buttons (a,s,d,arrows).

```
var wButton = false;

function newfunction()


document.querySelector('#keyButtonW').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    keyButtonPressed("wButton", true);
});

document.querySelector('#keyButtonW').addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    keyButtonPressed("wButton", false);
});

document.querySelector('#keyButtonW').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    keyButtonPressed("wButton", false);
});
```

Comment: What does the `keyButtonPressed` function look like?

Comment: Need a bit more information. What kind of character/movement are you trying to implement? Normally css is used with an image such as a gif or png. I would strongly suggest looking into a Javascript framework like jQuery to make your life easier. Other than that your event listeners should facilitate the "true/false" state of the buttons. See @Hotted24 answer for an example of switching keys.

Comment: Yes, sorry Im not really good at explaning this but the keyButtonPressed is actually the function i need to get this work. And Im making it to tablet/phone so i need to make movement buttons on the screen. Im looking for one function that takes care of all the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming translate is a method to move your char, maybe you should make a big maskArray :

```
var keyboard = [];
function keyDown(e)
{
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    keyboard[key] = true;
}

function keyUp(e)
{
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    delete keyboard[key];
}

function keyAction() {
    for (i in keyboard)
    {
        if (keyboard[i] == true)
        {
            switch(eval(i))
            {
                case 90: //Z
                    character.translateY(-1);
                    break;
                case 83: //S
                    character.translateY(1);
                    break;
                case 81: //Q
                    character.translateX(-1);
                    break;
                case 68: //D
                    character.translateX(1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);
```

Simply put keyAction() inside your main loop / rendering loop.

The value of this is to not make lags happen when you hit a button, and help with multiple pressing management =)

**EDIT**

To get the key numbers, simply put a console.log(key) at the end of keyDown().